# Android : Google Maps v2 in Asus Nexus 7 is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, nexus-7

I am working with `GoogleMaps v2` and tested my app in various android version (until 4.0. my application is working).

I tried to use my app on **Asus Nexus 7 (4.4)** but it does not work. Even the simplest `mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` is not working though the map is displayed and zooming works.

I researched some asus nexus 7 problem but no one have the same problem as me.

Update :

I already figured out what's happening.

the 
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

is correct and IS working. the problem is, it is so slow. 
I have tried the default MAPS app in nexus and it has the same behavior.

so it's not a bug or something. It is just too slow. :)

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem and solved it by  (( Go to Setting >> Locations> mode>> Battery savings >> then restart your device and set up again your app ))

Comment: This works for me as well, but I'm wondering why "High Accuracy" doesn't work. The Nexus 7 does have a GPS module, so this should work out of the box I would think.

Answer (score 1):

Google map now uses this to enable the My Location layer on the Map.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

You can view the documentation for Google Maps Android API v2 [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location).

They're using Location Client now to Making Your App Location-Aware,
you can also refer here for more information from these [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).

Comment: yes, sorry, my code above is incorrect, it should be
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

yet it still doesn't run.

here is my full code.

    public void init() {
 
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  }
  
  SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  if(mGoogleMap == null)
  {
   mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();
  }
  if(mGoogleMap != null) {
   mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  }
 }